# Select opens another select (loop)

Tags: html, html-select

I am kinda new to programming so I have no idea how to fix my issue.

So I have a `select id="one"`, and what I want is that when the user selects an option it shows a `select id="two"` and when the user selects an option it shows a `select id="three"` and so on...

I tried with 'display=none' but I don't really like that way because anyone can make the select show up without selecting an option. Is there any possible way of doing that?

Here is my first select:

```
<select class="form-control" id="one" required>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

And when the user picks an option this select must show up:

```
<select class="form-control" id="two" required>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
```

Thank you for your time and I hope you can help me!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: change HTML to reflect disabled="disabled". Javascript: jQuery('#one').change(function() { jQuery('#two').attr(disabled, false); }

Comment: I would use `display:none` for this purpose. Can you explain how anyone can make it show up? The select is supposed to show up.

Comment: @kfedorov91 I tried to use jQuery once. When the select changed i used the .html() to write the second select. But when the user changed the second select i couldn't write the third select. (i hope you understand what i wrote xP)

Comment: @StevenLinn i don't want the select to be disabled, I want it to be invisible (but without the display:none)

Comment: @forthe if someone uses the inspect element he can disable the display none before choosing an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is related to on select event not binding to dynamically created second select(id="two"). So try adding event listener via Jquery when you create new select box.

```
$("#one").on('change', function () {
    // Add second select box with id="two" here 
     $('<select id="two"><option></option></select><br/>').appendTo('body');
    //After adding select add the event listener
    $("#two").on("change", function(){
        // Write what you want to do here
    });
});
```

Comment: It actually works! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! <3

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It's very rough and only works on the basis of showing the next select in DOM order. You could add a `data` attribute to the select to determine which select to show when the value was changed.

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $(this).next('select').show();
  }
});

$('select:first').show();
```

```css
select {
   display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">- please select -</option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="">- please select -</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
  <option value="d">d</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="">- please select -</option>
  <option value="e">e</option>
  <option value="f">f</option>
</select>
```

If you're worried about someone showing the second select and without submitting something for the first then you can always run a check client side to see if both selects have a value or check server side.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question but I think that @jimmy found the solution that I was looking!